# How can I stop a worker destroying my town?

Tags: civilization-4

Playing Civ IV yesterday I got fed up with micromanaging my workers and turned one to automatic. I quite frequently do this in the middle game, but this time I happened to notice that it made a beeline for one of my towns and started converting it to a watermill. I wouldn't have minded it converting a cottage, even a hamlet, but a town?

Is there any way I can stop this, other than never letting my workers go fully automatic?

Comment: Seems like there was a setting about what workers are allowed to do on auto, I'll check.

Comment: I actually have this exact same problem.  You can usually micro manage when you have 2-3 cities, but once you get over 10 it becomes vaguely ridiculous.  What's worse, they'll remove a town and then sometimes build a cottage...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an option, under one of the menu screens (I don't have the game on this computer, so unfortunately I can't doublecheck *where* exactly) that does exactly what you seek:

"Automated workers leave existing improvements"

Which means once you've gotten your cities *generally* where you want them, you can automate the workers, who will finish up, build roads, etc, all the while leaving your own hand-placed improvements.

Comment: There's also a separate option for whether to allow automated workers to chop forests, so you can save them for specific things, build forest preserves, etc.

Comment: IIRC, the "Automated workers leave existing improvements" option is in the game options menu (one of the tabs next to Video settings, audio settings etc) - there's other things there as well like Display health bars, display enemy moves, etc.

Comment: You RC, and the option is exactly there.